# Solution of a linear, separable ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} +  P(x) y = Q(x)$$

be a linear ODE in its standard form. Using the integrating factor, it becomes

$$\mu(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + \mu(x) P(x) y = \mu(x) Q(x)$$

To determine $\mu(x)$:

$$\mu(x) P(x) = \mu'(x)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mathrm{d}x} = \mu(x) P(x)\\
\int \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mu} = \int P(x) \mathrm{d}x\\
\log \mu = \int P(x) \mathrm{d}x\\
\mu (x) = e^{\int P(x) \mathrm{d}x}$$

But I can't follow the last three steps. It should be

$$\int \mu' \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mu} = \log |\mu|$$

which is quite different from above. Why is it granted that $\mu' = 1$ and  $\mu = |\mu|$ is always positive?

$$$$

Comment: $\mu' $ is rarely $1$. I'm not sure where this came from. By definition $\int \frac{\mu'}{\mu}dx=ln|\mu|$.

Comment: @oshill that is in fact my question. See also the comment in the answer below.

Comment: oh, I see, so $\frac{d\mu}{dx}$ is $\mu'$, so the equality $\frac{d\mu}{dx}=\mu'(x)=\mu(x)\cdot P(x)$ becomes $\frac{\mu'(x)}{\mu(x)}=P(x)$ becomes $\int \frac{\mu'(x)}{\mu(x)}dx=\int P(x)dx$

Comment: In the formulation you have its kind of like they cancelled out the $dx's$ so you see $$\int \frac{d\mu/dx}{\mu}dx=\int \frac{d\mu}{\mu}$$

Comment: @oshill thank you, now I can get it!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting  confused between $dx$ and $d\mu$. $\int \mu'\frac {d\mu} {\mu}=\log |\mu|$ is not correct. [$\int \mu'(x)\frac {dx} {\mu(x)}=\log |\mu(x)|$ is correct but that is not relevant here].

Comment: Thanks, that was one mistake. But I still don't get the point: how to use $\displaystyle \int \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mu}$? You said $\displaystyle \int \mu'(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mu(x)} = \log |\mu(x)|$  is not relevant, but it is the only result I know about this kind of integrals.

Comment: @BowPark Which of the three steps in the proof is bothering you?

Comment: The step where $\displaystyle \int \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mu}$ is tranformed into $\log \mu$.

Comment: $\int \frac {d\mu} {\mu} =\log |\mu|+C$ is same as $\int \frac {dx} {x}= \log |x|+C$. The variable of integration is a 'dummy' variable.

Comment: Thanks, it is more clear now. The second doubt was about the sign: this way, only an always positive $\mu = |\mu|$ function can be obtained. Is that a limitation?